# Idle time in android?

Tags: android, idle-timer

How can I determine idle time in android? I wanted to show a popup if the application is idle for sometime,say some 60 secs.

Comment: see the correct answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985252/detect-when-application-is-idle-in-android

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the Android API provides anything that could help you with this. Also have in mind that most devices will turn off the screen after one minute of inactivity. It will be better to leave the user/device to select when the screen needs to be turned off. You can capture the screen off and on events using `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`. Instructions are provided [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/). You could show the dialog after the screen was turned off and on again.

Answer (score 1):

capture a time stamp just before last activity performed and start a `TimerTask` for one time execution with the difference period of time stamp captured + 60  secs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a handler that checks a boolean. If true show a notification. If the boolean is false ( then send a delayed empty message to the handler after 60 secs. Reset the boolean to true)
2. Send a delayed empty message to the handler after 60 secs
3. In your activity, on every user interaction reset the boolean to false.